# Export SharePoint 2010 look to 2013 instance

Tags: 2010, 2013, page-layout, migration, publishing-page

We need to take our SharePoint Enterprise 2010 instance's look-and-feel to a new 2013 instance. We didn't customize the master page but instead used page layouts in publishing pages to create the look we wanted for the sites. All the sites of our one site collection have publishing enabled.

We don't need to migrate the content (sites) to the 2013 instance. How do we export these custom page layouts and their CSS files, images, JavaScript (and anything else that is required) to 2013 from 2010?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and upload the files from/to the gallery.

URL: `http://www.yoursharepoint.com/_catalogs/masterpage`
or with
SharePoint Designer

Comment: Thanks, @Nattanan Schorer. Will this also work for the CSS and JavaScript files?

Comment: You can upload anything that its file type are not blocked and its size doesn't exceed the maximum upload size.

Blocked file types:https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx.
Maximum upload size: CA > Manage Web Application > General Settings > Maximum Upload Size